# Is it possible to show a video on discord bot camera?

Tags: python, video, discord, bots, discord.py

I have seen a discord bot existing that could show specific videos from its camera.

Is there any way I could add a command that would accept a direct video link and display it on a discord bot's camera? At least to show a video. (During streams)

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it may be possible but not yet available to the general public. I think maybe the bot you are referring to could have been taken down for breaking TOS. You might be able to do it but I do not think its allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way (yet) for a bot to stream a video in video format on Discord. Bots cannot stream anything other than audio on a voice channel.